# File conflict error during rpm install

Tags: permissions, rpm, file-ownership

I have two rpms xinstrument.rpm and xlog.rpm.
First the xinstrument.rpm should be installed followed by the xlog.rpm.

Both these rpms create and copy data into /opt/xinstrument-control/ directory.

But problem is when we install the second rpm xlog.rpm then we get conflict errors

```
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /opt/xinstrument-control from install of xlog_x86_64 conflicts with file from package xinstrument.x86_64
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

xinstrument.rpm when installed gives the following permission to the xinstrument-control directory

```
# ls -l /opt/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users 38 May 24 14:34 xinstrument-control
```

while xlog.rpm when installed gives the following permission to the xinstrument-control directory

```
# ls -l /opt/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 6 root sys  4096 May 16 05:43 xinstrument-control
```

Seeing the permissions and ownership of the directory is there any problem in it which is leading to conflict?
What else might be the cause of the conflict and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Only one can own that directory. Don't have both include it in their `%files` stanza.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the suggestion.
I will try to remove the directory from one of the rpm's spec file's %files section.

Comment: Startlingly, two packages can "provide" the same directory, as long as it's the same directory and permissions.  I don't think they can own the same file though.